# Python - replace values in a pandas data frame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I make the following replacements in a column of pandas data frame which has a datatype of int64?

-change 1 and 2 to 0

-change 3 and 4 to 1

-change 5, 6, 7 to 2

So that at the end I only have 3 levels for classification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `df` is the name of your dataframe and `column` is the name of a variable holding your column name as a string, then:

```
fun = lambda data: 0 if data < 3 else 1 if data < 5 else 2

df[column] = df[column].apply(fun)
```

will transform the column.